# I can't get all bytes from website

Tags: java, byte, inputstream, datainputstream

I'm trying to read all bytes from a web site but I think I don't get all bytes. I give a high value for bytes array length.  I used this method but it always returns an exception.

Here is the code:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s2.getInputStream());

byte[] bytes = new byte[900000];

// Read in the bytes
int offset = 0;
int numRead = 0;
while (offset < bytes.length
    && (numRead=dis.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
}

// Ensure all the bytes have been read in
if (offset < bytes.length) {
    throw new IOException("Could not completely read website");
}
out.write(bytes);
```

Edited Version:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bais = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = s2.getInputStream();
    byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; // Or whatever size you want to read in at a time.
    int n;
    while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
        bais.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.printf ("Failed while reading bytes");
    e.printStackTrace ();
    // Perform any other exception handling that's appropriate.
}
finally {
    if (is != null) { is.close(); }
}
byte[] asd = bais.toByteArray();
out.write(asd);
```

Comment: If you are using DataInputStream, is there any reason not to use `readFully` ?

Comment: @EricLeschinski: Um, I don't think so. The return value of `read` is the number of bytes read. He's not trying to read byte by byte.

Comment: What exactly does 'but I think I don't get all bytes' mean? How do you know? Any exceptions?

Comment: So what do you suggest to read byte by byte

Comment: Btw: your condition `(offset < bytes.length)` requires each site being larger than 900,000 bytes (+800 Kb)

Comment: Please don't use tabs in the future - I've edited your code so that it's not half way off the screen, but it would be helpful if you'd do it yourself in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if (offset < bytes.length)
```

You'll *only* trigger that if the original data is more than 900,000 bytes. If the response is entirely complete in less than that, `read()` will return -1 correctly to indicate the end of the stream.

You should actually be throwing an exception if `offset` *is* equal to `bytes.length`, as that indicates that you might have truncated data :)

It's not clear where you got the 900,000 value from, mind you...

I would suggest that if you want to stick with the raw stream, you use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [`ByteStreams.toByteArray`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) method to read all the data. Alternatively, you could keep looping round, reading into a *smaller* buffer, writing into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` on each iteration.

Comment: I'm wondering your alternative solution. How am I going to use ByteArrayOutputStream for each iteration

Comment: @AhmetTanakol: You create a single `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and use `baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` on each iteration - then use `toByteArray` when you've read all the data.

Comment: @JonSkeet :I tried to do what you said. Could you please check it. I edited my post. Still  I have a problem.

Comment: "I have a problem" is *very* vague. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this doesn't answer your *specific* question. However I really wouldn't hand-code this sort of thing, when libraries such as [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) exist and are debugged/profiled etc.

e.g. here's how to use the *fluent* interface

```
Request.Get("http://targethost/homepage").execute().returnContent();
```

[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is an alternative if you're dealing with grabbing and scraping HTML.